# NServiceBus - no handler for CompletionMessage

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I'm starting up a service that has only one handler - for a message defined in my application's message assembly.

The app is subcribing to this message type from a publisher app, and is receiving CompletionMessages during startup.

That's fine, except I'm getting this error message:

```
2014-05-06T14:35:02.4226418+01:00   15/Worker.15    Warning Failed raising 'transport message received' event for message with ID=f59e8698-b0dd-44f4-8e48-7185c8da7302\1275884
Exception of type System.InvalidOperationException:
   Message: "No handlers could be found for message type: NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage"
   Source: "NServiceBus.Core"
   Target Site: "Void HandleTransportMessage(NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.IBuilder, NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportMessage)"
   Help Link: ""
   Additional information specific to this exception:
   Stack Trace:
      at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleTransportMessage(IBuilder childBuilder, TransportMessage msg) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 1303
      at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 1220
      at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
      at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\impl\unicast\transport\NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional\TransactionalTransport.cs:line 480
```

Why isn't NServiceBus picking these messages up by itself with an internal handler?

Comment: What version of NServiceBus?

Comment: We have fixed that issue in later versions, see https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1752